# Python sqlite3 increase max columns

Tags: python, sqlite

sqlite3 by default sets SQLITE_MAX_COLUMN=2000 and you can recompile the CLI to increase the limit up to 32676. ([SQLITE3 increase Max Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43096246/sqlite3-increase-max-columns))

How can I translate this setting to work with the python module? (https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)

Comment: You'll need to recompile the SQLite library in order to change it. Nothing you can do in Python will be able to overcome this.

Comment: I've recompiled the C library, but can I get Python to use it as is?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: To phrase it better, what should I do with the compiled library to use it in Python?

Comment: You are violating [Swart’s Ten Percent Rule](http://michaeljswart.com/2013/05/swarts-ten-percent-rule/).

Comment: Someone already created a csv with >2000 columns and I need to process it. SQL is the easiest way. Not every question on here describes a new design to be used in production.

Answer (score 1):

You have to recompile and reinstall [_sqlite](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Modules/_sqlite) module. That means, though, that your programs that rely on this specific behaviour become non-portable — you cannot distribute your programs because you have to ask your users to recompile the module the same way. But for personal (or local to a company) use it's ok.

Comment: Could you help me understand how to do this? I don't see any references to SQLITE_MAX_COLUMN in the _sqlite code. How does this module relate to the code from https://www.sqlite.org/download.html?

Comment: It's not an independent module. It's a python wrapper for libsqlite. So you have to recompile libsqlite and recompile Python from sources using recompiled libsqlite.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to recompile libsqlite3 and us it via ctypes or cffi. Like this: https://gist.github.com/achimnol/3021995 or [How to code and wrap with ctypes a python function needed as callback by sqlite3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44437521/7976758) That way you don't need to recompile Python.