# SQLITE increase Maximum number of Columns

Tags: sqlite, qgis

I've got a table with too many columns in QGIS software so I would like to increase the maximum column limit in SQLite. The limit is set to 2000 columns and I would like to increase it.

The exact same issue as shown here :

[SQLITE3 increase Max Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43096246/sqlite3-increase-max-columns)

The problem is that I'm quite a beginner and I'm missing some steps to start from step 3 and 4. I'm completely lost here.

Could someone give me a hand?

Comment: Needing that many columns is a sure sign of bad database design.

Comment: Do you mean that the data could be wrong ? Those are pixels values for pollutants on a map. There are many different pixels values on this map. It is a very precise map

Comment: You should store your data in a way that doesn't require thousands of columns. Maybe a one-to-many relationship. Or as coordinates and the value for that location. Depends on the details of your data.

Comment: I see... But the problem is that I cannot even see the data, QGIS prevents me from doing it because of this SQLITE limit...